# Access host or URL info in Silverlight out-of-browser

Tags: .net, silverlight, out-of-browser

I'm building a Silverlight app which will be deployable to different websites easily, and from within the application, I need to access the domain/host that the Silverlight is hosted at. So, I know for apps within the browser window, this code would perfectly work:

```
HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.Host;
```

The problem is, I need this app to be installed and be run in out-of-browser mode too. However, when I call the same code in OOB mode, I get an exception, which is perfectly normal as SL in not running in a browser. But logically, the SL app has been installed from somewhere, and I need to access that "origin" URL (or at least, the original host is enough for me in this project). Simply put, if the app is installed from http://example.com/example.xap, how can I access the very string "http://example.com/example.xap" programatically while running out of browser? I won't be knowing this in advance as the app will be modular and be deployed to any domain. Is creating a settings file in isolated storage and setting the domain string if not set the only option, or is there a more trivial way?

Thanks, Can.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the address (even in OOB) using `Application.Current.Host.Source`

Comment: I'm hosting a few web pages on the same web application as my XAP (actually for use in a silverlight WebBrowser control), and this helped me programmatically find the URL.  Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can acquire the address of the Xap from the `BaseAddress` of a fresh instance of a `WebClient`.

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 string xapAddress = client.BaseAddress;
```

The `BaseAddress` is initialised witth the application origin address and will work in an OOB.